# How to write a for loop for a sine curve with a pause after each iteration

Tags: r

I was given the code:

```
plotsin <- function(z) {plot(function(x) (sin(x+z)) ,0,20, ylab="")}
```

I am supposed to write a for loop that calls `plotsin(i)` for `i` from 1 to 100. In the for loop, after every call to `plotsin`, call R function `Sys.sleep(0.15)` to let the program insert a pause of length 0.15 seconds between each drawing of the sine curve.

I was thinking the code should look something like this:

```
for (i in 1:100){print(i+ Sys.sleep(0.15))}
```

but I know I am missing an aspect of it. All help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Separate commands should be put on separate lines or separated by semicolons: `for (i in 1:100){print(i); Sys.sleep(0.15)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i in 1:100) {
  plotsin(i)
  Sys.sleep(0.15)
}
```

The `i` refers to the value that will be placed in that specific *i* th iteration. That is the value you need to include in the `plotsin()` function.

Comment: Please provide some description to your solution and what was root-cause in OP's code. That will make your answer complete and clear.

Comment: I added a line. I have trouble determining what is there to describe, really.